# How to change the hover pseudo class of an element using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, pseudo-class

I have a few elements on a div that can be moved around by the user.
In order to make their draggability obvious, I've been using the `hover` pseudo class.

So I have

```
.textbox
{ /*some style*/
}
```

and then I have a hover pseudo class for the draggable corners of the textbox:

```
.textbox:hover .ui-resizable-sw {background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)  !important;}
.textbox:hover .ui-resizable-se {background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)  !important;}
.textbox:hover .ui-resizable-nw {background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)  !important;}
.textbox:hover .ui-resizable-ne {background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)  !important;}
```

However, what I need to do now is to only let the CSS become applicable after a user clicks on a certain activate button (`switchOn`). If I leave the above lines in the CSS stylesheet then the styles will always apply, but I want them only to apply sometimes, and not at other times.

I've checked this and know how to do it:
[Can I do this with the :hover pseudo class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353397/can-i-do-this-with-the-hover-pseudo-class)

The problem is I don't want to have to do it using jquery like this because jQuery can be slow and there might be quite a few elements on the user's `div`, I don't want things to get sluggish. Instead of changing the style dynamically via jquery, is there any way to attach or detach the css style to the object?

Something like this:

```
function switchOn()
{
     $('.textbox').addStyle('.textbox:hover .ui-resizable-ne, 'background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)  !important;');

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the solution can be applying another class on click on the button then change the css defs.

```
$('#my-button').click(function(){
    $('.textbox').toggleClass('active'); // .addClass('active');
})
```

then

```
.textbox.active:hover .ui-resizable-sw {background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)  !important;}
.textbox.active:hover .ui-resizable-se {background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)  !important;}
.textbox.active:hover .ui-resizable-nw {background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)  !important;}
.textbox.active:hover .ui-resizable-ne {background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)  !important;}
```